# ListView - stretch single item across the whole ListView height

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

If I have a **single** item in an **ArrayAdapter** on a **ListView**, I would like to **stretch that one item all over the** **ListView** **height** (so I have the text of the one item in the center of the screen).

Like this:

[image]

This is really easily done with RecyclerView (the image above) but in my case I can't afford rebuilding ListView screens on RecyclerView now. I tried setting the height of the layout item to the screen height "match_parent" or in code, overriding the 80dp value. It didn't have any impact on my situation, the result looked like this:

[image]

this is how I am creating the ArrayAdapter:

```
string[] noResultsItem = { Resources.GetString(Resource.String.no_network) };
playlistListView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.no_result_row, Resource.Id.textTop, noResultsItem);
```

This is the layout for the ArrayAdapter item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/noResultsRow">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I can imagine a solution with hiding and showing the ListView and replacing it with a TextView that would be centered but I don't like that solution that much.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070361/single-row-to-fill-parent-listview-height

Comment: @AbidKhan cheers, somehow didn't see that before, I will try that out now

Comment: Can you please post your activity code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating my own simple adapter for one item:

```
public class SingleItemAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private readonly Context context;
    private readonly ListView listView;
    private readonly int textViewResourceId;
    private readonly int resource;
    private readonly int textResourceId;

    public SingleItemAdapter(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }

    public SingleItemAdapter(Context context, ListView listView, int resource, int textViewResourceId, int textResourceId)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.textResourceId = textResourceId;
        this.listView = listView;

        listView.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
        listView.CacheColorHint = Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            var inflater = LayoutInflater.From(context);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(resource, parent, false);
            return CustomizeView(view);
        }
        else
        {
            return CustomizeView(convertView);
        }
    }

    private View CustomizeView(View view)
    {
        view.LayoutParameters.Height = listView.Height;
        var textTop = view.FindViewById<TextView>(textViewResourceId);
        textTop.Text = context.GetString(textResourceId);
        return view;
    }

    public override Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return context.GetString(textResourceId);
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return textResourceId;
    }

    public override int Count => 1;
}
```

This is the updated layout of the item that's being contained in the adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/noResultsRow"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Layout height as

```
 android:layout_height="80dp"
```

replaces it on

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`
and gravity should be center or you can take LinearLayout

Comment: This doesn't work - it produces exactly the same result as I described above.

Comment: do you want to stretch the text to fill the row @JakubHolovsky

Answer (score 0):

It is the bad practice using the item of listview for showing that there is no data. Use instead of Textview or any Imageiew that represent there is no data with your listview inside FrameLayout and play with visibility of views like

```
if(data.size > 0){
 listview.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
 textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
 listview.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
 textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```